# jQuery toggle fade: Can't get div to fade out/in on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I click on the black button, the red div fades out and the blue div fades in. However, when I click the black button a second time to switch it back, there is no fade out/in. How can I make it so that the blue div fades out and the red div fades back in?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddac5391/1/

**HTML**

```
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>

<div id="primary"></div>
<div id="contact-keebs"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contact-button {
    background: #000;
    background-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#primary {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
#contact-keebs {
    background: blue;
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var c = 0;
$('#contact-button').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (c++ % 2 == 0) {

        $(this).addClass('work-button').text('Work');
        $('body').addClass('contact-content');
        $('#contact-keebs').stop().fadeIn(500).show();

    } else {

        $(this).removeClass('work-button').text('Get in touch');
        $('body').removeClass('contact-content');
        $('#contact-keebs').stop().fadeOut(500).hide();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.show()` and `.hide()`; and  to let the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` animation complete(before stopping the animation) use `.finish()` before `.stop()`.

If you don't use `.finish()`, the `div`s will sometimes stuck at a point where their opacity is not `1`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ddac5391/8/)(try clicking rapidly) demonstrating this.

```
$('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeIn(500);
```

and

```
$('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeOut(500);
```

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddac5391/7/)**</kbd>

Complete Demo:

```js
var c = 0;
$('#contact-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (c++ % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('work-button').text('Work');
    $('body').addClass('contact-content');
    $('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeIn(500);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('work-button').text('Get in touch');
    $('body').removeClass('contact-content');
    $('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeOut(500);
  }
});
```

```css
#contact-button {
  background: #000;
  background-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#primary {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
#contact-keebs {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>
<div id="primary"></div>
<div id="contact-keebs"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix it. You don't need to add show and hide after the fadeOut, fadeIn : http://jsfiddle.net/ddac5391/6/

```
if (c++ % 2 == 0) {

            $(this).addClass('work-button').text('Work');
            $('body').addClass('contact-content');
            $('#contact-keebs').stop().fadeIn(500);

        } else {

            $(this).removeClass('work-button').text('Get in touch');
            $('body').removeClass('contact-content');
            $('#contact-keebs').stop().fadeOut(500);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$('#contact-keebs').stop().fadeOut(500).show();`